# Как сделать, что бы выбирался только один checkbox?

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте!

Есть пачка инпутов:

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="field1" id="oneMostCheck">
<input type="checkbox" name="field2" id="oneMostCheck">
<input type="checkbox" name="field3" id="oneMostCheck">
<input type="checkbox" name="field4" id="oneMostCheck">
<input type="checkbox" name="field5" id="oneMostCheck">

<button id="saveForm" type="submit">Применить</button>

</form>
```

Как сделать, например на JQuery, что бы из них мог быть выделен только один и форма не отправлялась (выскакивал алерт), если ни одного выделенного.
Т.е. чекнул первую галочку, чекнул вторую, у первой чек снялся.

radiobutton не могу использовать тут.

Спасибо.

Comment: Можете обосновать, чем не угодил radiobutton?

Comment: @Mit5x не давайте один id многим элементам. Им это не нравится.

Comment: @Mit5x "форма не отправлялась (выскакивал алерт), если ни одного не выделенного" -это значит ни одного выделенного?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov name нужны разные. В зависимости это этого у нужной строки параметр добавится.

Comment: @KirillKorushkin верно

Comment: Разные могут быть `value`. Какая разница, вы получите не сервере `$_GET['field1'] == 'on'` или `$_GET['field'] == ''field1''`?

Answer (score 4):

Вариант на css

```css
input[name=field]{
  display: none;
}
input[name=field] + label{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
}
input[name=field]:checked + label{
  background: green;
}
#saveForm{
  pointer-events: none;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #888;
}
input[name=field]:checked + label ~ #saveForm{
  pointer-events: auto;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="field" id="mc1">
  <label for="mc1"></label>

  <input type="radio" name="field" id="mc2">
  <label for="mc2"></label>

  <input type="radio" name="field" id="mc3">
  <label for="mc3"></label>

  <input type="radio" name="field" id="mc4">
  <label for="mc4"></label>

  <input type="radio" name="field" id="mc5">
  <label for="mc5"></label>

  <button id="saveForm" type="submit">Применить</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Сбрасывать все чекбоксы кроме текущего нажатого, проверять перед отправкой формы по количеству. И уберите одинаковые id у элементов, это является ошибкой в HTML, поскольку допускаются только уникальные значения. А вообще для этого используются радиокнопки и вы городите велосипед.

```js
$('form').eq(0).on("change", function(e){ 
    $('input[name^=field]').each(function()
    { 
      if(e.target != this)
        this.checked = false; 
    });
})

$('form').eq(0).on('submit', function() {
     return $('input[name^=field]:checked:enabled').length == 1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="field1">
<input type="checkbox" name="field2">
<input type="checkbox" name="field3">
<input type="checkbox" name="field4">
<input type="checkbox" name="field5">

<button id="saveForm" type="submit">Применить</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вообще советую использовать Radio для этого, но если вам надо Checkbox, можно использовать следующую конструкцию.

И да, одно замечание: у вас идет дублирование ID, этого категорически нельзя делать и я убрал его..

```js
$('form#my_form > :checkbox').on('change', function() {
  var checkbox = $(this);
  var name = checkbox.prop('name');
  if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
    $(':checkbox[name="' + name + '"]').not($(this)).prop({
      'checked': false,
      'required': false
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#my_form {
  width: 110px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my_form">
  <label>Первый</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="field" required>
  <br>
  <label>Второй</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="field" required>
  <br>
  <label>Третий</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="field" required>
  <br>
  <label>Четвертый</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="field" required>
  <br>
  <label>Пятый</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="field" required>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button id="saveForm" type="submit">Применить</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

используйте метод `siblings()` для поиска соседних чекбоксов, и снимайте флажки с `prop('checked', false)`.

При отправке формы проверяйте число отмеченных флажков в `submit` и возвращайте `false`, чтобы прервать отправку.

```js
$("input").change(function(){
   $(this).siblings("input").prop('checked', false);
});

$("form").submit(function(){
    if($("input:checked").length > 1){
       alert('error!');
       return false;
    } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
   <input type="checkbox" name="field1">
   <input type="checkbox" name="field2">
   <input type="checkbox" name="field3">
   <input type="checkbox" name="field4">
   <input type="checkbox" name="field5">
 
   <button id="saveForm" type="submit">Применить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: .length < 1, чую так вернее будет)

Comment: @KirillKorushkin с чего в друг? написано, что  нельзя отправлять, если больше одного флажка стоит. 0 или 1 можно.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам нужно выделить ровно один чекбокс, то это не чекбокс, а радиокнопка. Если Вам нужно, чтобы радиокнопка выглядела как чекбокс, то задайте ей нужный стиль.

Далее, не нужно бомбить пользователя сообщениями "Ты дурак, выбери что нибудь". Просто блокируйте кнопку отправки, пока не будут установлены валидные параметры

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#saveForm').prop({disabled: true});
  $('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
    $('#saveForm').prop({disabled: false});
  });
});
```

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  -moz-appearance: checkbox;
  -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <!-- Первую кнопку делаем выбранной и скрываем ее, иначе кнопки будут в состоянии "grayed" -->
  <input type="radio" name="field" checked="checked" style="display: none;">
  <input type="radio" name="field" value="field1">
  <input type="radio" name="field" value="field2">
  <input type="radio" name="field" value="field3">
  <input type="radio" name="field" value="field4">
  <input type="radio" name="field" value="field5">

  <button id="saveForm" type="submit">Применить</button>

</form>
```

Comment: А откуда юзер узнает какие параметры валидные? Инструкцию рядом деражть? Эти чек боксы не ед. элементы формы

Comment: и мне нужно что бы name у инпутов были разные

Comment: @Mit5x Зачем? Сделайте разные value. Как узнает? Обычно, требуемые поля помечают в интерфейсе звездочкой

Comment: @Mit5x И да - держать инструкцию. Юзер не должен угадывать, что Вы от него хотите. Требования должны озвучиваться сразу

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#someform [type="checkbox"]').click(function(event) {
  var $chck = $(this).find('[type="checkbox"]');
  $chck.removeAttr('checked').filter(event.target).prop('checked', 'true');
 $(this).parent().find('[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="someform">
  <input type="checkbox" name="field1" id="oneMostCheck">
  <input type="checkbox" name="field2" id="oneMostCheck2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="field3" id="oneMostCheck3">
  <input type="checkbox" name="field4" id="oneMostCheck4">
  <input type="checkbox" name="field5" id="oneMostCheck5">
  <button id="saveForm" type="submit" disabled>Применить</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что можно воспользоваться переключением путем создания кнопок и стилизовать их под чекбоксы:

```html
<form id="someform" class="myCheckboxStyle">
    <button name="field1" id="oneMostCheck">filed1</button>
    <button name="field2" id="oneMostCheck2">field2</button>
    <button name="field3" id="oneMostCheck3">field2</button>
    <button name="field4" id="oneMostCheck4">field2</button>
    <button name="field5" id="oneMostCheck5">field2</button>
</form>
```

В данном случае выбор будет однозначно один. Не забудьте указать метод отпраки формы